# Failed to import Metal Functions into Swift

Tags: ios, swift, metal

I tried to add metal files to my project but when I am trying to import them, It throws this error:

> 2019-05-11 20:07:33.715399+0200 Camera[363:16969] -[MTLRenderPipelineDescriptorInternal validateWithDevice:], line 2395: error 'vertexFunction must not be nil.'
>
> -[MTLRenderPipelineDescriptorInternal validateWithDevice:]:2395: failed assertion `vertexFunction must not be nil.'

Here is my code what I have done so far :

```
let pipelineDescriptor = MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor()

pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = .bgra8Unorm
pipelineDescriptor.vertexFunction = defaultLibrary.makeFunction(name: "vertexMixer")
pipelineDescriptor.fragmentFunction = defaultLibrary.makeFunction(name: "fragmentMixer")
    
do {
    renderPipelineState = try metalDevice.makeRenderPipelineState(descriptor: pipelineDescriptor)

} catch {
    fatalError("Unable to create video mixer pipeline state. (\(error))")
}
```

Has anyone encountered this before?
Please help me if anyone know what is the solution.

Comment: Based on what you’ve shown us, there are no functions with the specified names in the default library. You should make sure that the Metal file(s) that are being compiled into the default library actually contain functions with those names.

Comment: I am using this 

let defaultLibrary = metalDevice.makeDefaultLibrary()!

and apparently it doesnt find any functions in libraries.

Comment: The fact that you're getting a library object instead of `nil` means that there _is_ a default library in the app bundle, but it doesn't contain functions with the names you're asking for. So you need ensure that one of the .metal files included in the Compile Sources build phase of your app target actually has definitions for those functions.

Comment: It seems like  'defaultLibrary.makeFunction(name: "vertexMixer")' return nil ,which means function loaded failed.